# Excel treats unicode characters as text

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts, unicode

I have received an excel file which contains data from government website, whose text is in Hindi language.

When I open the csv file, it displays the hindi texts in unicode characters like the following: à¤¬à¤¹à¥‡à¤°à¥€,,

I have installed hindi fonts but it didn't work. It seems like excel is treating these characters as text instead of unicode. Any leads on how to solve this issue? I uploaded it in google sheets but still doesn't work. However, when I copy this text to ChatGPT, it does display the word in Hindi its reply.

I have also tried "importing" this data as utf-8 in excel and stata and it isn't working still.

Comment: It's an Excel file or a CSV file? (A CSV file might open in Excel by default, but is a test file.)  Can you open the file in a text editor and see if you see the Hindi data?

Comment: It's a CSV file. I tried opening in text editor and it still shows as à¤¬à¤¹à¥‡à¤°à¥€,,

Comment: Then the issue is obviously not Excel, but the file itself. I'd bet that after opening once in Excel (with the non-Unicode encoding) you saved it back to the CSV, so now the file it garbage. Can you download the CSV file again from the source and open in a text editor to see if you can see the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file may perhaps not be written in Hindi, but may contain Unicode
characters without a
[byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
so that Excel is reading it as text and not as Unicode.

To force Excel to read the file as Unicode :

- Go to the Data pane
- In the group "Get & Transform Data" click "From Text/CSV"
- When the dialog opens, in the drop-down of "File origin",
  try another encoding.

When you find the right encoding, to keep it for this file, save it
as a Windows spreadsheet.

Comment: Tried all the unicode encodings, didn't find the right encoding. Thanks anyways. The file contains data scraped from a hindi website and the hindi texts are the ones which shows à¤²à¤¾à¤²à¤®à¥à¤¨à¥€ à¤¸à¤¿à¤‚à¤¹ characters.

Comment: So this is a real Hindi file in an unknown encoding. Have you installed Hindi as a second language? This is done in *Settings > Time & language > Language & region*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just tried that, still not working.

Comment: Perhaps you should post this file online for analysis.

Comment: I don't see any option to upload the file here. Any forum that you can suggest?

Comment: OneDrive, Dropbox etc.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1twsda0W9WtY886yYgLoP4Y3VvEdCHyov/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=100307402826824899492&rtpof=true&sd=true    Uploaded the file here

Comment: The file is protected against access...

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. I have made it accessible. Thanks!

Comment: Auto-translate translates "लालमुनी सिंह रामसुन्‍दर सिंह "बरली" as "Lalmuni Singh Ramsunder Singh "Barli". Is this correct and the language is well-detected? If yes, then this is encoded in Unicode.

Comment: Yes this is correct and well-detected. But I have 4 million rows in the main file. How to allow excel to detect the language?

Comment: Why do you need to detect the language? The downloaded spreadsheet displays well on my Office 365, probably by automatic detection, and I have never installed Hindi. Perhaps the problem is that the CSV is in Unicode but lacks the [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). I'm not sure that my downloaded file is identical to your computer, or whether Google has added it automatically.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. The downloaded file in my computer shows à¤¬à¤¹à¥‡à¤°à¥€,, instead of the hindi text. Nonetheless, I appreciate your effort. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You uploaded an Excel file; not the csv. Need to see the actual csv file. And with 4 million rows, you'll need to split it if you want to see it in Excel which only has a bit more than 1 million rows per worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

When importing to excel, you should try other character encodings too.

I think it is certainly a character encoding issue, and not a missing font type issue.

If it was a missing font issue, then the displayed characters would be empty squares or some other uniform characters, indicating missing font. For example this: □

Comment: I tried all the character encodings, still not showing up the hindi text. Thanks anyways!